# Doubly stochastic matrices that remain doubly stochastic after conjugating by the character table of a finite abelian group

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, linear-algebra, finite-groups

I am curious if anything is known about the following.

Let $\Gamma$ be a finite abelian group, and let $\chi$ be its character table, normalized so that it is a unitary matrix. E.g., if $\Gamma$ is $\mathbb{Z}_n$ then $\chi_{ij} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\omega^{ij}$ where $\omega$ is a primitive $n^\text{th}$ root of unity. Is there any known characterization of the following *convex* set

$$\mathcal{M}_\Gamma := \{M \in \mathbb{C}^{\Gamma \times \Gamma} : M \text{ is doubly stochastic and } \chi^*M\chi \text{ is also doubly stochastic} \}.$$

Maybe it is worth mentioning that $\mathcal{M}_\Gamma$ is closed under matrix multiplication and contains all the automorphisms of $\Gamma$. Also, it is not hard to show that if $M \in \mathcal{M}_\Gamma$, then

1. $\chi^* M \chi \in \mathcal{M}_\Gamma$ (and vice versa);
2. $M_{\mathrm{id},a} = M_{a,\mathrm{id}} = \delta_{\mathrm{id},a}$ for all $a \in \Gamma$ (where $\mathrm{id}$ is the identity element of $\Gamma$);
3. $M_{a,b} = M_{-a,-b}$ for all $a,b \in \Gamma$.

In fact, $\chi^*M\chi\vec{1} = \vec{1} = (\chi^*M\chi)^T\vec{1}$ is equivalent to (2), and $\chi^*M\chi$ being real is equivalent to $M_{-a,-b} = \overline{M_{a,b}}$ for all $a,b \in \Gamma$ which for real $M$ is just (3) above.

Thus, in a sense the difficult thing seems to be understanding when $\chi^*M\chi$ is nonnegative.

**Is anything known about the set $\mathcal{M}_\Gamma$ (e.g., its extreme points)? Even answers for particular $\Gamma$ (e.g., $\Gamma = \mathbb{Z}_2^3$) would be interesting to me.**

For what it's worth, for $\Gamma = \mathbb{Z}_4$, there are 4 extreme points:
$$\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\end{pmatrix}, \quad \begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&0\\0&0&0&1\\0&0&1&0\\0&1&0&0\end{pmatrix}, \quad \begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&0\\0&0&\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}\\0&\frac{1}{2}&0&\frac{1}{2}\\0&\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}&0\end{pmatrix}, \quad \begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&0\\0&\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}&0\\0&\frac{1}{2}&0&\frac{1}{2}\\0&0&\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: Equivalently, you are looking for the intersection of ${\bf DSt}_\Gamma$ with its conjugate by the character matrix. Btw, I am not sure that the question makes sense for a general abelian group ; because the conjugacy depends on the way you order the rows and the columns of $\chi$, and there is some arbitrariness there. It depends upon the choice of an isomorphism between $\Gamma$ and its dual. Of course $\Gamma^*$ is isomorphic to $\Gamma$, but not in a canonical way. Only if $\Gamma={\mathbb Z}_n$, your question does not depend upon the choice of an isomorphism.

Comment: @DenisSerre I don't think the question depends on an isomorphism between $\Gamma$ and its dual. Perhaps I have swapped rows and columns from the usual definition, but I mean for $\chi$ to have rows indexed by $\Gamma$ and columns indexed by $\Gamma^*$. Then given a matrix $M = (m_{ab})$ indexed by $\Gamma$, the matrix $\chi^* M \chi$ is a matrix indexed by $\Gamma^*$ whose $f,g$-entry is $\sum_{a,b \in \Gamma} \overline{f(a)}g(b)m_{ab}$. This will either be doubly stochastic or not irrespective of any isomorphism between $\Gamma$ and $\Gamma^*$.

Comment: @DenisSerre However, I have been sloppy in item (1) in the question.

Comment: To view an automorphism as an element of $\mathcal M_\Gamma$, do you regard it as a particular kind of permutation, and then identify a permutation with the corresponding permutation matrix?

Comment: @LSpice Yes. So if $\sigma$ is an automorphism of $\Gamma$, by saying that $\sigma$ is in $\mathcal{M}_\Gamma$ I mean that the permutation matrix with $P_{a,b} = \delta_{a,\sigma(b)}$ is in $\mathcal{M}_\Gamma$.